# Can't size doughnut chart from chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

Not sure how to set height/width for doughnut chart, tried with this:

```
<div style="height: 168px">
    <canvas id="chart-area" style="height: 168px"/>
</div>
```

I have text underneath the chart, and this only change the position of text & graph rather than the size of the doughnut chart.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 26):

try this in chart's option confirg

```
options = {
  maintainAspectRatio : false
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because for what OP pretended to do, this option is exactly what he's asking for. http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#responsive-charts

Answer (score 9):

Try to set height of canvas inline:

```
<div style="height: 168px">
     <canvas id="chart-area" height="168px"/>
</div>
```